# How to run OSS dependent application? "/dev/dsp"

Tags: ubuntu-12.04, alsa, voice-command

I'm using ubuntu 12.04 LTS - sound works fine.

I've tried to execute pocketsphinx for some tests with voice recognition, but it depends on OSS to work.
It crashes with the message:

```
ad_oss.c(103): Failed to open audio device(/dev/dsp): No such file or directory
```

Googli'n around my first fix attempt was installing the package "oss-compat" - but the lack of success led me to find out it is just a misleader - an empty bogus package.

Then I tried:

```
$> padsp pocketsphinx_continuous
...
ioctl(NONBLOCK) failed: Invalid argument
```

Finally, the (dead?) [sphynx wiki FAQ](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/wiki/faq#qfailed_to_open_audio_device_dev_ds) states:

> compile pocketsphinx with ALSA support by installing alsa development headers from a package libasound2 or alsa-devel

Alsa-devel does not exists in my distro, but I've installed libasound2-dev and gstreamer0.10-pocketsphinx - then re-compiled pocketsphynx - no changes.

Now I'm out of ideas and the sphynx forums seem to be down.
Anyone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just as a few guesses:

- Nothing changed in pocketsphynx's support of ALSA because, after installing the ALSA headers, you compiled pocketsphynx with `./configure` and did not specify `--prefix=/usr` as a command line option to `configure`, so it installed it into `/usr/local` path. `/usr/bin` version of pocketsphynx is being launched instead, so your installed version isn't being picked up.
- Pocketsphynx's build system has a flag you have to specify in order to enable ALSA support explicitly, and you didn't set that flag? Try `./configure --help` to see if you have to specify `--enable-alsa` or something.
- If you still can't get ALSA support working, try configuring your system for OSS Proxy support. You can start with the "How to Test" instructions at [here](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Features/OSSProxy) but skip steps 3 through 6. Also, you will need to separately compile `osspd` from source. The new home of osspd is on [SourceForge](http://sourceforge.net/projects/osspd/). The purpose of `osspd` is to emulate a **real** OSS device in userspace using *Character Device In Userspace* (CUSE) kernel module, and forward the audio through the kernel to PulseAudio. It's more compatible with programs because certain things like non-blocking I/O and MMAP can be emulated with osspd that can't be emulated with a libc preload hack like `padsp` or `aoss`.

Comment: Indeed I was not specifiying the --prefix / and totally ignored the pocketsphynx compilation time on the error messages, thanks.

Comment: You are getting compile-time errors in pocketsphynx? What are the errors?

Comment: I've searched for such kind o flag to enable ALSA - didn't found any. Running configure with proper prefix, make clean, make, sudo make install.. No effect, same errors. So I'm trying osspd. I've compiled it, followed the instructions on the link and runned osspd - but syslog pops this: osspd: Creating dsp (14:3), adsp (14:12), mixer (14:0) > CUSE: failed to register chrdev region

Comment: Oh, no compile error - when I run the binary, along with the "Failed to open audio device(/dev/dsp)" it popsthe binary compile date/time - this should warn me about not running the right version.

Comment: Ah :) You get that error `failed to register chrdev region` if you have [`CONFIG_SOUND_OSS_CORE_PRECLAIM`](http://cateee.net/lkddb/web-lkddb/SOUND_OSS_CORE_PRECLAIM.html) enabled in your kernel... so you'll have to recompile the kernel with this flag unset. :( Anyway, does the pocketsphynx compile complete successfully, and what are you using as the `--prefix`?

Comment: Also please come to [Root Access](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/118/root-access) chat if you want to troubleshoot in real-time :)

Comment: Looks strange to me that the instructions on the link to fedoraproxy are setting the permissions on /dev/dsp before it exists.

Comment: I wrote those instructions on the fedora page a long time ago. Probably some flaws with it. The absence of the `/dev/dsp` device is due to the `chrdev` error you're getting, which is due to that config flag of the Linux kernel as I mentioned.

Comment: oh! so many tests and I've never tried the 'aoss' you mentioned - works like a charm. Thanks for all the help allquixotic

Answer (score 1):

I've found the easiest way to do oss emulation for one specific program on Ubuntu is to install `alsa-oss` which provides an `aoss` command.  Then run `aoss program` to magically give *program* oss emulation.

(The other way is to install oss4 drivers, but then you have to use those instead of alsa, I don't think there's any good way to have oss4 and alsa coexist?)